# Give focus to form2

Tags: c#, forms

I have a program with two forms, but Form1 is opening up over Form2, which isn't good since you need to use Form2 first.  How can you force focus to Form2 when the application runs?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) for Form2 instead of `Show`.

You can also use [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to get the already opened form `Form2` and then call its `Focus` method like:

```
if(Application.OpenForms["Form2"] != null)
   Application.OpenForms["Form2"].Focus();
```

Comment: The ShowDialog idea does open the second form first, but the form is blank? A webpage should open up.

Comment: @eltel2910, that has nothing to do with the question, that may be a bug in form2 from doing its work.

Comment: Form2 has one line....open a webpage and it works fine, its just that it is hidden behind form1.  I just need both forms to open up, but form2 to be the focus.